# Выполнение команды оболочки из perl-скрипта

Tags: perl

Изучаю perl, решил написать небольшой скриптик для личных нужд.
Среди прочего, скрипт должен выполнить переход в указанную папку и запустить там приложение. Проблема пока возникла именно с переходом в папку.

Пытался сделать так:

```
my $fld="/home/user/work/folder";
my $cdm="cd $fld";
system($cdm);
```

При выполнении скрипта получаю сообщение, что нет такой папки.

Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано? Папка точно существует.

Comment: например, не хватает прав.

Comment: @KoVadim, было такое предположение, но не понимаю, у кого и каких? Сам скрипт запускается из папки того же пользователя, которому принадлежит целевая папка.  На скрипт поставил права 777...

Comment: я бы запустил через strace/ltrace и посмотрел реальные запросы и реальные ответы.

Comment: @KoVadim, я пробовал прогнать в дебагере: ```perl -d ....``` . Вроде все формируемые строки соответствуют ожиданиям, показывает, что ```$cdm="cd /home/user/work/folder"```,  а при вызове ```system($cdm)```  пишет, что нет такой папки. C strace/ltrace пока не знаком, вечером попробую разобраться. Спасибо.

Comment: my $cdm="cd $fld";
system($cdm); это исполняется не в вашем процессе. есть chdir()

Comment: @hobo-mts, да, кажется это будет лучше. Спасибо. А не подскажете, куда посмотреть на предмет того .в каком процессе выполняется мой вариант?

Comment: @Юрий Козлов, `cd` -- внутренняя команда оболочки, поэтому ваш `system()` скорее всего вызовет `bash -c $cdm`. `bash` изменит каталог у себя, но у вашего процесса останется прежний.

Comment: @hobo-mts Спасибо. Заработало. Оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ, чтобы я мог его принять.

Comment: осталось только понять, почему оно возвращало, что такого каталога нет. Или это возвращала **другая команда**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my $cdm="cd $fld"; system($cdm);` это исполняется не в вашем процессе. есть `chdir()`.
`cd` -- внутренняя команда оболочки, поэтому ваш `system()` скорее всего вызовет `bash -c $cdm`. `bash` изменит каталог у себя, но у вашего процесса останется прежний.

Comment: Ответ несовсем верен. ИМХО, Perl и не пытается запустить `sh -c`, а ищет программу `cd` и не находит. У меня в cygwin: `perl -e 'system("cd abc"); print "$!, $?\n";'` даёт `No such file or directory, -1`

Comment: `$ which -a cd` -->
`which: no cd in (...)`. Но `chdir()` таки есть.

Answer (score 1):

По прочтении `perldoc -f system` оказалось, что перловый system() делает не то же самое, что сишный, и поведение его зависит от передаваемого аргумента.

В случае автора вопроса шелл не запускается, а делается fork()+*exec("cd") по каждому элементу $PATH*. exec("cd") обламывается, т.к. такой программы в пути действительно нет. Выдаётся сообщение `Can't exec "cd": Нет такого файла или каталога at ./test.pl line 4`, неверно интерпретированное автором как сообщение об отсутствии целевого каталога.

Comment: У меня было подозрение, что я что-то неправильно понимаю в сообщении об ошибке, но не хватило знаний прислушаться к этому сообщению. Не пришло в голову, что не находит он именно ```cd```